# GroupBy using string value returning multiple groupings with the same key

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, character-encoding

I have a weird problem attempting to group objects using Linq `GroupBy()` with a string value.

I'm attempting to group objects using the `Value` property, which is a string, like so:

`objects.GroupBy(o => o.Value)`

If I do this, I get more groupings than I should. For example in code I get ~150 groups, many with the same keys. However if I query the table I'm pulling from in SQL Server:

`SELECT DISTINCT Value FROM Object`

I get 57 or so unique values.

I got to thinking there could be an encoding issue causing this. After messing around some I found that this:

`objects.GroupBy(o => new Regex("").Replace(o.Value, string.Empty))`

Gets rid of the duplicate values and matches the 57 results of the SQL query above. The column in the database is defined as `NVARCHAR(50)`.

What's a good way to inspect and clean this data so this isn't necessary? I still haven't really found out for sure what the issue is, I just stumbled upon something that works. I would like to find out more definitively what is happening here.

Edit, I checked the grouping using this query:

```
var groups = objects.GroupBy(o => o.Value)
    .Select(g => new { g.Key, Chars = g.Key.ToCharArray() })
    .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
    .ToList();
```

And then converting the char array to ints as suggested, the duplicate Keys have the same values when converted to their integer value.

And there are numerous duplicate groups, with no differences in characters that are apparent. There are many "100% Assumed" groups, while others are grouped into a single key like they should be. Note "100% Assumed" is just an example and not the only Key with multiple groupings.

[image]

Comment: You are saying they are duplicate without providing any real evidence they are duplicate. We are saying `GroupBy` doesn't think they are duplicate and there must be a reason. What is the type of `objects`?

Comment: Thanks for trying to do what I suggested. It needs one more tweak to give what I was needing: try `Chars=string.Join(",", g.Key.ToCharArray().Select(x=>(int)x))` ( I'm not at my PC so can't check my syntax, hope this is OK)

Comment: @Richardissimo I updated the image from the debugger with the results of that query.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. The contents appear literally identical, which leaves me without an explanation for why they aren't being grouped together. But at least your question now has more evidence, so someone else might be able to suggest further things to try.

Comment: I've been assuming that "o.Value" is type 'string', based on the information in the question if not, let us know what it is; because it's the `IEqualityComparer` for whatever type that is which is getting that wrong, and I can't believe that the one for string doesn't work properly. I'm sure @NetMage would appreciate an answer to his question.

Comment: Yes, `Value` is a `string`.

Comment: (Relocating this comment here from an answer I'm going to delete) Just as an aside, remember that SQL will use a collation to work out DISTINCT, just like C# will use a culture and case sensitivity for comparing strings; and maybe there's a difference. For example, you can do things like this... `SELECT DISTINCT Value COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS FROM Object`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's because of the **"Chars = g.Key.ToCharArray()"**.

If it's me, I would use **Distinct**, rather than GroupBy in this case, because of the way you check the result in db's side using "SELECT DISTINCT Value FROM Object". Unless you will do some aggregations later.

So I would suggest, in this case :

```
var groups = objects
    .Select(o => new { o.Value }).Distinct()
    .Select(g => new { g.Value, Chars = g.Value.ToCharArray() })
    .OrderBy(o => o.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think you have understood the question. The question is why does `objects.GroupBy(o => o.Value)` not group the same values together. The "Chars" part that you are referring to is where the OP is trying to demonstrate that there are duplicate Keys which are not being grouped together, it is not part of the problem scenario.